# Taking batch of items from list of class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have below set of code -

```
class className
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? OtherField { get; set; }
}

// Create a list of className objects
List<className> lst = new List<className>
{
    new className { Name = "Sagar", Value = "1", OtherField = null },
    new className { Name = "Dinesh", Value = "2", OtherField = null },
    new className { Name = "Suresh", Value = "3", OtherField = null }
};
```

I want to capture first 2 items from list only.

For this I tried -

```
var batch = lst.Take(2).ToArray();
```

Here I got null reference exception as I have null OtherField value in lst.

I tried with -

```
var batch = lst
    .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
    .Where(x => x.Index < 2)
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToArray();
```

Here also I am getting null reference exception.

Then I tried with -

```
var batch = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
    .Select(index => lst[index])
    .ToArray();
```

Here also I got null reference exception.

All these null reference exceptions are due to otherField value is null , which is always going to be null in lst.

How can I perform this without using for loop?

Comment: I tried with your codes and get no exception. Does it happen if you make another project?

Answer (score 1):

At least your first line of code is correct, and does not throw any exception on my side.

```
lst.Take(2).ToArray();
```

Are you sure that `lst` is not `null` at this moment ?

Comment: if I check batch in quick watch it is null reference exception

Comment: and if you check `lst` in quick watch ?

Comment: lst is with proper set of values which we assigned

Comment: Do you have a `ToString()` method inside `className` that would throw `NullReferenceException` in quick watch ?

Comment: No , I dont have

Comment: Instead of using the quick watch, could you add a breakpoint on this line of code and inspect `lst` ? `lst` being `null` is the only reason I can think of ^^